# ExtJS6: Not replacing proxy :id for read when called

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

ExtJS6 model is not forming correct proxy urls for dynamic parameters

Model looks like

```
Ext.define('Testt.model.User', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['id', 'name'],

  proxy: {
   type: 'ajax',
   api : {
    read : 'api/user/:id',
    create : 'api/user',
    update : 'api/user/:id',
    destroy : 'api/user/:id'
   },
   reader : {
    type : 'json'
   },
   writer : {
    type : 'json'
   }
 }
});
```

Now when called to load a user record like

`Testt.model.load(27, { success: function(rec){console.log(rec)}})`

It does not replace `:id` with actual 27

Comment: Where in the ExtJS docs did you find the `:id` syntax?

Comment: This syntax is used in Router. But anyhow the question would how we could get Ext.data.Model replace id in proxy dynamically

Comment: Please provide a link to the ExtJS docs that state that this syntax is correct. Also I cannot find any ExtJS docs that state that you can call load from the model prototype (statically) and provide the id as first parameter. The samples I find say otherwise.

Comment: Yes, there is nowhere in the Model documentation that says to do this... Read the doc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the REST Proxy type (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.data.proxy.Rest.html) then the IDs will be automatically appended to your URLs. You don't need the ':id' syntax in the urls.

Check out this fiddle to see it working: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cri